# PayPal fees paid by buyer

Tags: paypal

Does anyone know whether I can put paypal fees onto the buyer - so that I get the full amount I'm charging?

Comment: Not a programming question... you've asked 8 questions and not accepted one of them. Is this a 'bugmenot' type account?

Comment: I don't know what bugmenot is - but these are  genuine questions - how do you actually accept the answer - I couldn't find any option on the post page?

Comment: To accept an answer, click the checkbox outline next to the best answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't. Just charge them the difference, what you want to charge + 1.4-3.4% + transaction charge - (20p in the UK).

Comment: Charge (amount + 3.25) / (1 - x), where x is 1.4 - 3.4 %, depending on your deal.

Answer (score 1):

You should ask PayPal if there's a way to do this through their system.

But if not, you could take the price of your product, compute the PayPal fee, and add it to the total cost that you submit to PayPal.

Answer (score 1):

Only way is to charge him/her extra - compute the ammount you're going to pay taxes and add it to overall sum.